# file_get_contents('php://input'); with application/x-www-form-urlencoded;

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I've read a few questions about the subject here on but couldn't find the answer I'm looking for.
I'm doing some $.post with jQuery to a PHP5.6 server.

```
$.post('/', {a:100, b:'test'}, function(data){
}, 'json');
```

The encoding from the console is

```
Content-Type    application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
```

If I try to read the POST data with a regular $_POST, PHP5.6 alerts me

```
PHP Deprecated:  Automatically populating $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. To avoid this warning set 'always_populate_raw_post_data' to '-1' in php.ini and use the php://input stream instead
```

So then I've tried the suggestion, added always_populate_raw_post_data = -1 in php.ini and

```
json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
```

PHP5.6 alerts me that it is invalid

```
PHP Warning:  First parameter must either be an object or the name of an existing class
```

So I've dumped file_get_contents("php://input") and it's a string.

```
a=100&b="test"
```

So I've parsed the string and encoded then decoded

```
parse_str(file_get_contents("php://input"), $data);             
$data = json_decode(json_encode($data));
var_dump($data);
```

And THEN I finally have my $data as an object and not an array, as a true JSON object.

I've resorted to keep on using $_POST for now... But then I'm wondering about upgrading PHP..

**The question here is that, is there a straighter forward solution to this or does it mean using file_get_contents("php://input") also means doing the parsing decoding encoding shenanigans?**

**Edit:** so it appears this doesn't work either on multi levels json's. 
Consider the following:

```
{"a":100, "b":{"c":"test"}}
```

As sent in Ajax/Post

```
{a:100, b:{c:"test"}}
```

Doing

```
parse_str(file_get_contents("php://input"), $post);
var_dump($post);
```

Will output

```
array(2) {
 ["a"]=>string(8) "100"
 ["b"]=>string(16) "{"c":"test"}"
}
```

Or doing (as suggested)

```
parse_str(file_get_contents("php://input"), $post);
$post= (object)$post;
```

Will output

```
object(stdClass)#11 (2) {
 ["a"]=>string(8) "100"
 ["b"]=>string(16) "{"c":"test"}"
```

}

**How do I transform file_get_contents("php://input") into a true object with the same "architecture" without using a recursive function?**

**Edit2 : My mistake, the suggested worked, I got side tracked in the comments with JSON.stringify which caused the error.
Bottom line: it works with either json_decode(json_encode($post)) or $post=(object)$post;**

**To recap, using jQuery $.post :**

```
$.post('/', {a:100, b:{c:'test'}}, function(data){
}, 'json');

parse_str(file_get_contents("php://input"), $data);             
$data = json_decode(json_encode($data));
```

**or**

```
parse_str(file_get_contents("php://input"), $data);
$data= (object)$data;
```

**No need to use JSON.stringify**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My mistake, the suggested worked, I got **side tracked in the comments with JSON.stringify** which caused the error. Bottom line: it works with either json_decode(json_encode($post)) or $post=(object)$post;
The answer Michael gave is correct but side tracked me and I left the error in my code. JSON.stringify is only useful when posting the data from a form as I replied in the comment.

Answer (score 14):

Receiving serialized/urlencoded POST data in the request's POST body as you are, you've correctly transformed it into an array with `parse_str()` already.

However, the step of encoding then decoding JSON in order to transform that into the *object* (as opposed to *array*) you're looking for is unnecessary.  Instead, PHP will happily cast an associative array into an object of class `stdClass`:

```
parse_str(file_get_contents("php://input"), $data);
// Cast it to an object
$data = (object)$data;

var_dump($data);
```

A little more information is available [in the PHP documentation on type casting](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php#language.types.typecasting).

Comment: Ok this only works for the 1st level. Say my data structure is {"a":"test", "b":{"c":123}}, it will output "b" as a string "{"c":"123"}" inside my object.

Comment: Sorry updated for nothing, your comment/statement about JSON.stringify is wrong and while doing some test, inserted the error. Your answer is valid tho. Sorry for removing the validity.

Comment: @Eric The point of `JSON.stringify()` was indeed to avoid having to read the raw POST entirely, and instead to allow PHP to handle the post data natively in the `$_POST` superglobal (with one additional `json_decode()`).  I didn't mention it in my answer because it was not intended as a component of this answer.  For what it's worth, I did flag the comment thread a couple days ago for the mods to come and clean out (which hopefully would have avoided this confusion) but the flag still has not been acted on.

Answer (score 9):

In order to send raw json data, you have to stop jQuery from url-encoding it:

```
    data = {"a":"test", "b":{"c":123}};

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url:  '...',
        data: JSON.stringify(data), // I encode it myself
        processData: false          // please, jQuery, don't bother
    });
```

On the php side, just read `php://input` and `json_decode` it:

```
$req = file_get_contents("php://input");
$req = json_decode($req);
```