# AngularJS: login function not working in PHP code

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

Currently, I am trying to create a login function using AngularJS framework. I tried creating a login function but its executing the else statement. Can I know how to solve this problem.

This is my login.php code:

```
$params = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'),true);

if(!isset($_SESSION)){ 
    session_start(); 
}

include "classes/filmService.class.php";
$db = pdoDB::getConnection();
header("Content-Type: application/json");

if(isset($params['userid']) && isset($params['password'])){

    $userid   = $params['userid'] ;
    $password = $params['password'];
    $service  = new FilmService();
    $result   = $service->loginRob($userid,$password);
    echo $result;
}else{
    echo '{"status": "fail", "message": "Please enter email & password la!!."}';
}
```

This is my services.js code:

```
this.login = function (userID, passwd) {
            var defer = $q.defer(),
            data = {
              //action: 'loginRob',
              userid: userID,
              password: passwd
            };

            $http({
                method: 'POST',
                url: loginUrl,
                params: data,
                cache: true,
                headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}

            }). // notice the dot to start the chain to success()
            success(function (response) {
                defer.resolve({
                    data: response.status, // create data property with value from response
                    result: response,
                    user: response.username
                });
                console.log(response);
            }). // another dot to chain to error()
            error(function (err) {
                defer.reject(err);
            });
            // the call to getCourses returns this promise which is fulfilled 
            // by the .get method .success or .failure
            return defer.promise;
        };
```

This is my controller.js code:

```
.controller('LoginController',
            [
                '$scope',
                'dataService',
                '$location',
                '$window',
                '$rootScope',
                function ($scope, dataService, $location, $window, $rootScope){
                    $scope.check_login = function($event,userID,passwd){
                        if(userID && passwd){
                            dataService.login(userID,passwd).then(
                                function (response){
                                    if(response.result.status=='ok'){
                                        $scope.user = response.user;
                                        $rootScope.$broadcast("passuser", $scope.user);
                                    }else{
                                        $scope.message = response.result.message;

                                    }
                                },

                                function (err) {
                                    $scope.status = 'unable to connect to data' + err;
                                }
                            );

                            $scope.reloadRoute = function () {
                                $location.path('/#');
                                //$window.location.reload()
                            }//end of reload route fnction
                        }
                    }//end of function check_login 
                }
            ]
        );//end of login controller
```

This is the recordSet code for the login:

```
function getLoginRecord($sql, $elementName = "ResultSet", $params = null) {
    $stmt     = parent::getRecordSet($sql, $params);
    $recordSet = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $nRecords = count($recordSet);
    $loginSuccess = "";
    if ($nRecords == 0) {
        $status = 'error';
        $message = json_encode("Invalid username or password");
        $result = '[]';
        $loginSuccess="{\"status\": \"$status\", \"message\":$message}";
    }
    else {
        $status = 'ok';
        $message = json_encode("Success");
        //$userName=json_encode($recordSet[0]['username']);
        $result = json_encode($recordSet);
        // $session = Session::getInstance();
        // $session->setProperty('user', $recordSet[0]['username']);
        // $session->setProperty('user_email', $recordSet[0]['email']);
        $loginSuccess="{\"status\": \"$status\", \"message\":$message }";
    }
   return $loginSuccess;
}
```

I really appreciate if there is someone to help me on this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you get any errors in the console? Did you injected the dependencies properly?

Comment: no errors @AlonEitan its only showing `echo '{"status": "fail", "message": "Please enter email & password la!!."}';` in the console once I `console.log(response);`

Comment: Please take a look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25937775/file-get-contentsphp-input-with-application-x-www-form-urlencoded

Comment: So how is `$scope.check_login()` being called and where do values for arguments come from? Are you sure they are even defined in the controller and therefore in request? Seems strange that the userId and password aren't scope variaables bound to form with `ng-model`

Comment: Far too many unknowns here and no debugging/troubleshooting information given. Use browser dev tools network to inspect actual request to see exactly what is sent. Need to isolate where problem is

Comment: Also `params` in `$http` is used for GET not POST. You have no `data` property

Comment: The same code my friend used its working for him..just mine is not working

Comment: @charlietfl after changing params to data i am getting this error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid shorthand property initializer
angular.js:10071 Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: dataServiceProvider <- dataService`

Comment: My guess is you have a syntax error from doing the change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several issues with the way `$http` is set up.

You are using `params` in `$http` config which is for GET not POST. Need to set `data` for POST

You are switching the contentType to form encoded but trying to receive as json in your php. If you want to send as form encoded then numerous changes need to be made

---

For now lets send as json data so try switching to:

```
$http.post(loginUrl, data). // notice the dot to start the chain to success()
        success(function (response) {
            defer.resolve({
                data: response.status, // create data property with value from response
                result: response,
                user: response.username
            });
            console.log(response);
        }). // another dot to chain to error()
        error(function (err) {
            defer.reject(err);
        });
```

Then in php if you still don't get proper response you need to do some very basic debugging to see if data is actually being sent.

Comment: its working now but the login validation is not working

Comment: Well now you are really creating a whole new question and it shouldn't be added to this one. I gave you the solution to fix the original question and you should start a new one regarding the validation that includes a proper problem statement